# Android 4.4 port compile error

Tags: android, porting

I've been working on an android 4.4 kitkat port to D2ATT and I keep getting this build error:

```
including ./hardware/qcom/display/Android.mk ... 
build/core/copy_headers.mk:15: warning: overriding commands for target out/target/product/d2att/obj/include/qcom/display/copybit.h' 
build/core/copy_headers.mk:15: warning: ignoring old commands for targetout/target/product/d2att/obj/include/qcom/display/copybit.h' 
build/core/copy_headers.mk:15: warning: overriding commands for target out/target/product/d2att/obj/include/qcom/display/copybit_priv.h' 
build/core/copy_headers.mk:15: warning: ignoring old commands for targetout/target/product/d2att/obj/include/qcom/display/copybit_priv.h' 
build/core/base_rules.mk:134: *** hardware/qcom/display/msm8960/liblight: MODULE.TARGET.SHARED_LIBRARIES.lights.msm8960 already defined by device/samsung/d2-common/liblights. Stop.
```

Does anyone know how to fix this or what it means? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means `MODULE.TARGET.SHARED_LIBRARIES.lights.msm8960` is defined by both `hardware/qcom/display/msm8960/liblight` and `device/samsung/d2-common/liblights` files, so you either remove one of them from the linking -if you don't have source code- or comment this definition in one of them.